# Getting atomic time with Android

Tags: android

I am using the following code to connect and retrieve the UTC time from an AtomicTime server from an Android device:

```
public static final String ATOMICTIME_SERVER="http://132.163.4.101:13";
BufferedReader in = null;

try 
{
    URLConnection conn = new URL(ATOMICTIME_SERVER).openConnection();
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String atomicTime;
    while (true) 
   {
      if ( (atomicTime = in.readLine()).indexOf("*") > -1) 
      {
         break;
      }
   }

   ... do something
}
catch ...
```

It does not return any data. When accessing the URL from a browser, we get the following:

`55884 11-11-19 07:40:22 00 0 0 824.5 UTC(NIST)`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
String atomicTime = "";
try 
{
    Socket socket = new Socket("132.163.4.101", 13);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    in.readLine(); // Ignore leading blank line
    atomicTime = in.readLine();
    socket.close();
} 
catch....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no HTTP service on TCP port 13. There is daytime service. You should use Socket instead of URLConnection. Or maybe find some NTP implementation for Android.